# Custom Indexing using Nutch with hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, nutch

I am trying to create solr index of crawled documents using Nutch with hadoop and custom plugins. The following error occurs while running the code from Nutch.

```
hadoop@hadoopmaster:~/Nutch1.4/runtime/deploy$ bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/ ../../CR_UNL_NEW6/crawldb -dir ../../CR_UNL_NEW6/segments
17/03/15 16:58:13 INFO solr.SolrIndexer: SolrIndexer: starting at 2017-03-15 16:58:13
17/03/15 16:58:13 INFO indexer.IndexerMapReduce: IndexerMapReduce: crawldb: ../../CR_UNL_NEW6/crawldb
17/03/15 16:58:13 INFO indexer.IndexerMapReduce: IndexerMapReduces: adding segment: hdfs://hadoopmaster:54310/CR_UNL_NEW6/segments/20150814104354
17/03/15 16:58:13 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 15
17/03/15 16:58:13 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201703151429_0004
17/03/15 16:58:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/03/15 16:58:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201703151429_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilter not found.
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilters.<init>(IndexingFilters.java:63)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.configure(IndexerMapReduce.java:62)
    ... 22 more
```

FYI: i am using Nutch1.4, solr3.6 and hadoop1.2.1 for the process.
i need to know why the error occurs and if possible the procedure to add custom plugins and run the index using Nutch with hadoop.

Comment: How did you ended up writing/compiling/adding your plugin to Nutch? did you follow the indications on https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample ?